# Google Api translate authentication without environment variables

Tags: java, authentication, kotlin, google-api, google-translate

I'm trying to use Google translate API without using environment variables, but it seems I'm missing something. Here's the kotlin code I'm using:

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate
import com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions
import java.io.FileInputStream

class StringsTranslator {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            TranslateOptions.newBuilder().credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
                    FileInputStream("ktools/google-apis-credentials.json")
            )

            val translate = TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().service

            val text = "Hello world!"
            val translation = translate.translate(
                    text,
                    Translate.TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
                    Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage("es")
            )

            println("$text = ${translation.translatedText}")
        }
    }
}
```

I basically took this example and adapted it:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/translate/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/translate/QuickstartSample.java

But I'm getting this exception:

Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateException: The request is missing a valid API key.

The file is there as downloaded from google (otherwise it'd throw an IOException before anyway), and it seems the TranslateOptions.newBuilder() has no problems with it, so I think I'm doing something wrong in the middle, or missing some step so those options are used by the translate service further.

TIA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out just a second after posting the question. I'll leave this code here in the hope it'll be eventually useful for someone else.

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate
import com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions
import java.io.FileInputStream

class StringsTranslator {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            val translate = TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
                    FileInputStream("ktools/google-apis-credentials.json")
            )).build().service

            val text = "Hello world!"
            val translation = translate.translate(
                    text,
                    Translate.TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
                    Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage("es")
            )

            println("$text = ${translation.translatedText}")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the first answer is a Java version, but I use Python google-tranlate-client.
below is the solution.

```
def g_translate(self, target_language):
    import os
    credential_path = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/key.json'
    from google.oauth2 import service_account

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(credential_path)
    translate_client = translate.Client(credentials=credentials)

    translation = translate_client.translate(self.local, target_language=target_language)

    return translation['translatedText']
```

I don't want use env variable cause need to config in all the server env, I guess this way is more convinient on production env

> [Github Question](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5449)